# I try connect a network wifi in ubuntu through one script on python

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, wifi

i want to connect a wifi network through python on terminal, in Ubuntu 20.04 i connect with this line:

```
nmcli dev wifi con "ssid" password "hereP"
```

i want to do this with python but i found two problems, i can run commands of linux with "import so:so.system("nmcli dev wifi con "ssid" password "hereP"")"

first issue: when the password is an alert appears that the password is wrong, How can I show the error by console?

second issue: i want to implement a for with one array of possible passwords, i new in programming, i know that for syntax is a (for word in words) but i don't know execute in this situation.

history not relevant but i tell it.

i had a mifi (mf93d) i changed the password and not remember which is, and I am unable to connect in any other way to change the password and it is not allowed to restore to factory settings so the only way I have is to recover the password from the wifi, which I know starts with "Mifiune".

Please help me! I had a lot of fun trying to solve this problem on my own but I feel stuck

Answer (score 0):

You can use subprocess module for that like this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["nmcli", "dev", "wifi", "con", "ssid", "password", "hereP"])
```

But remember not to include space inside quotes and remember to type inside lists if there are more parameters.

Hope it will help